# The new Crashlytics Method

Tags: ios11, crashlytics

I just downloaded Crashlytics through Cocoapods yesterday,
I Started integrating it to my project following some videos in the internet.
I liked the way of integration without fabric pod (the new way) so I did that successfully.

[image: Screen shot of successful Crashlytics settings.]

Everything is working fine except for uploading DSYM files. I tried the following code:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp
"${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios
"${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

But that give me an error while compiling :

```
Running upload-symbols in Build Phase mode
Validating build environment for Crashlytics...
Validation succeeded. Exiting because upload-symbols was run in validation mode
[31merror: Could not get path for GoogleService-Info.plist[0m
/Users/ahmedal-mashhoor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MAGICWORLD-bksejwnexokchwftspvscdgsjjek/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MAGICWORLD.build/Debug-iphoneos/MAGICWORLD.build/Script-78DFB3242419196A006596CC.sh: line 4: /Users/ahmedal-mashhoor/Desktop/MagicWordiOS/GoogleService-Info.plist: Permission denied
/Users/ahmedal-mashhoor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MAGICWORLD-bksejwnexokchwftspvscdgsjjek/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MAGICWORLD.build/Debug-iphoneos/MAGICWORLD.build/Script-78DFB3242419196A006596CC.sh: line 5: /Users/ahmedal-mashhoor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MAGICWORLD-bksejwnexokchwftspvscdgsjjek/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MAGICWORLD.app.dSYM: is a directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

What am I doing wrong here?, help please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS and FirebaseCrashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60821249/ios-and-firebasecrashlytics)

Comment: checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047863/7435893

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the right code:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p iOS "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

Comment: The above works, however you may have to change iOS to ios (all lower case) if you get the error


Showing All Messages
[31merror: Invalid platform name (iOS). Valid platform names are: 'ios', 'mac', 'tvos'[0m

Comment: why do you need to run `upload-symbols` command yourself? 
`run` script does that already 

Comment: What do you mean by run script?